# Found match using "For each r in Intersect..." and if "r = item"; how do I select the next few cells in the row to paste into a different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using these functions to find a match between one workbook and another.  Upon doing so, I need to grab the cells from r's row, and past them at the bottom of my other workbook (Named newbook).  I know this finds a match per a msgbox test.

I have tried using

```
lw = newbook.sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").End(xlDown).row
```

and then

```
newbook.sheets("Sheet1").cells(lw+2, 15).print raw.cells(2)
```

.... however this is yielding an error "Object doesnt support this property or method".
-Please excuse the commented out sections, these were alternative attempts.

```
Sub lastitem(newbook)
Dim lw As Long
Dim m, raw As Range
Dim rngPrevious As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim myrow As Long

Item = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 51).Value

Set rngPrevious = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Programing 
with extra itd step\Previous_Data").Sheets("Data") _
.Range("A1:I500")  'adjust to suit
 Set thirdwb = Workbooks("Previous_Data.xlsm")

'm = Application.Match(Item, rngPrevious, 0)

'If Err.Number = 0 Then
 For Each r In Intersect(thirdwb.Sheets("Data").Range("a:a"), 
thirdwb.Sheets("Data").UsedRange)

 If r = Item Then


Set raw = thirdwb.Rows(r) 'get a reference to the matched row

'lastRow = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

If newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2") <> "" Then

lw = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
If lw = "1048576" Then
lw = "2"
End If

newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lw + 2, 15).Print raw.Cells(2)

End If

End If

Next r

   'Set raw = rngPrevious.Rows(m) 'get a reference to the matched row

'lastRow = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

'If newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2") <> "" Then

'lw = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").End(xlDown).Row
'If lw = "1048576" Then
'lw = "2"
'End If

'newbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(lw + 2, 15).Print raw.Cells(2)

'End If
'MsgBox ("Error")
'End If
rngPrevious.Close

End Sub
```

receiving "Object doesnt support this property or method" error in the If r = item then statement

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Sub lastitem(newbook)

    Dim lw As Long, thirdwb As Workbook, Item
    Dim shtData As Worksheet, shtOne As Worksheet
    Dim rngPrevious As Range, colFound As Collection, c

    Set shtOne = newbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set thirdwb = Workbooks.Open( _
           "C:\Users\userX\Desktop\Programing with extra itd step\Previous_Data")

    Set shtData = thirdwb.Sheets("Data")

    Item = shtOne.Cells(2, 51).Value
    'find all matches on Data sheet
    Set colFound = FindAll(shtData.UsedRange.Columns(1), Item)
    Debug.Print colFound.Count & " matches for '" & Item & "'"

    If colFound.Count > 0 Then
        'Are you expecting >1 matched row? 
        'Code below will need to be adjusted if yes
        For Each c In colFound
            lw = shtOne.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            shtOne.Cells(lw + 2, 15).Value = c.EntireRow.Cells(2).Value
        Next c
    End If

    thirdwb.Close False 'don't save

End Sub


'find all occurences of "val" in range "rng" and return as a Collection
Public Function FindAll(rng As Range, val) As Collection
    Dim rv As New Collection, f As Range
    Dim addr As String

    Set f = rng.Find(what:=val, after:=rng.Cells(rng.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not f Is Nothing Then addr = f.Address() 'first cell found

    Do Until f Is Nothing
        rv.Add f
        Set f = rng.FindNext(after:=f)
        If f.Address() = addr Then Exit Do 'exit if we've looped back
    Loop

    Set FindAll = rv
End Function
```